# Fake Moving GPS iOS

Tags: ios, swift, gps

I'm doing some development using CoreLocation which detect the location entry and exit. I want to test the function without driving around. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: In the iOS Simulator, select Debug > Location, then choose your location.

Comment: @LouFranco, i don't think its not the duplicate of what you mentioned.... Please open it so we can help user

Comment: @LouFranco I need moving gps so I can detect entering and exiting location not only fixed gps location.

Comment: The answer for this question is using a gpx and adding an array of location with times for walk simulation, is needed for triggering events working with geofences

Comment: @ReinierMelian Is there any way I can do something like dragging the location on the phone direclty? because I need to show some demo without having to drive around, in Android there is a fake GPS app that we can use to move around but I can't find anything similar on iOS. any idea?

Comment: The only way that i found was with gpx files in XCode enviroment, I use this method to simulate a walk through several points of my city from my work desk